# #define many times without #undef，is it legal？

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

For example, I define *AA* for three times, is it legal？：

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define AA 10
#define AA 20
#define AA 30
int main() {
    printf("AA");
}
```

Comment: Add `-Wall` at your compilation command and see what it tells you.

Comment: It's not illegal, but is a bad idea to use like this. And don't ignore the warning while compiling.

Comment: Legal: Yes - Useful or even a good idea: No. But C allows you to use a lot of constructs that are neither useful nor good ideas. Get used to it ;)

Comment: or better, use -pedantic

Comment: Please specify which language you are interested in.   C and C++ are not the same language

Answer (score 10):

This is not legal in both C and C++.

Quotes from draft C standard [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> 6.10.3 Macro replacement
>
> Constraints
>
> 1 Tw o replacement lists are identical if and only if the preprocessing tokens in both have
>   the same number, ordering, spelling, and white-space separation, where all white-space
>   separations are considered identical.
>
> 2 An identiﬁer currently deﬁned as an object-like macro shall not be redeﬁned by another
>   `#define` preprocessing directive unless the second deﬁnition is an object-like macro
>   deﬁnition and the two replacement lists are identical. Likewise, an identiﬁer currently
>   deﬁned as a function-like macro shall not be redeﬁned by another `#define`
>   preprocessing directive unless the second deﬁnition is a function-like macro deﬁnition
>   that has the same number and spelling of parameters, and the two replacement lists are
>   identical.

Quotes from draft C++ standard [N4582](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4582.pdf):

> 16.3 Macro replacement [cpp.replace]
>
> 1 Two replacement lists are identical if and only if the preprocessing tokens in both have the same number,
>   ordering, spelling, and white-space separation, where all white-space separations are considered identical.
>
> 2 An identiﬁer currently deﬁned as an object-like macro may be redeﬁned by another `#define` preprocessing
>   directive provided that the second deﬁnition is an object-like macro deﬁnition and the two replacement lists
>   are identical, otherwise the program is ill-formed. Likewise, an identiﬁer currently deﬁned as a function-like
>   macro may be redeﬁned by another `#define` preprocessing directive provided that the second deﬁnition is a
>   function-like macro deﬁnition that has the same number and spelling of parameters, and the two replacement
>   lists are identical, otherwise the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 6):

No it is not. The C standard clearly states that it is a constraint violation, 6.10.3 p.2:

> An identifier currently defined as an object-like macro shall not be
>   redefined by another
>   `#define` preprocessing directive unless the second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two replacement lists are
>   identical.

So as for all constraint violations, your compiler is only obliged to issue a "diagnostic" that is an explanatory message. It may or may not continue to compile your code.

To state it more directly, your code erroneous and your compiler must tell you.

Answer (score 5):

It is obviously not recommended even thought it can compile.
In your example, you can just use `#define AA 30` once. In other cases, if you want to define a macro when it is not defined yet, you can use conditionals:

```
#ifndef AA
#define AA 30
#endif
```

Also, I think you mean `printf("%d\n", AA);` to print the macro, because `printf("AA");` will just print the string literal `AA`.

Comment: @LPs This is debatable, the compile warns for the redefinition, but the expanded is 30.

Comment: Yes. Exacly what I wrote. OP code gives 30, your gives something different .

Comment: I don't get it? what do you mean?

Comment: Why printf("AA"); will only print the string literal "AA", but not the macro's value "30"

Comment: Nothing important at all. I mean that your solution leave the first definition value to AA, but It avoid warnings at all. OP code generates warns and the value will be 30.

Comment: @pengxu Because the `"AA"` is a string literal, the thing inside the double quotes will not be treated as a macro.

Answer (score 3):

Lets start by correcting your printf to something useful: `printf("%d", AA);`

Compiling it with `gcc` will produce two warnings that "AA" is redefined.  Warnings are really important and should be avoided in C, but the result will be as expected (30).