# Is it possible to redefine a macro without the use of ‘undef’?

Tags: c++, c, libspatialindex

I am trying to make sense of the [libspatialindex](https://libspatialindex.org/doxygen/) source code. Being new to c++, I have difficulty wrapping my head around the concept of macros. 
The library’s API wrapper for C, [sidx_api.cc](https://libspatialindex.org/doxygen/sidx__api_8cc_source.html#l01663), directly and indirectly includes numerous headers two of which seemingly define the same macro, concerned with interfacing a dynamic library, without ‘undef’:

[Tools.h](https://libspatialindex.org/doxygen/Tools_8h_source.html)

```
45 #if (defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64 || defined WIN32 || defined WIN64) && !defined __GNUC__
46  #ifdef SIDX_DLL_EXPORT
47  #define SIDX_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
48  #else
49  #define SIDX_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
50  #endif
51 
52  // Nuke this annoying warning. See http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/VisualStudio/warningC4251.html
53 #pragma warning( disable: 4251 )
54 
55 #else
56  #define SIDX_DLL
57 #endif
```

[sidx_export.h](https://libspatialindex.org/doxygen/sidx__export_8h_source.html)

```
29 #pragma once
30 
31 #ifndef SIDX_C_DLL  
32 #if defined(_MSC_VER)
33 # define SIDX_C_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
34 # define SIDX_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
35 #else
36 # if defined(USE_GCC_VISIBILITY_FLAG)
37 # define SIDX_C_DLL __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
38 # define SIDX_DLL __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
39 # else
40 # define SIDX_C_DLL
41 # define SIDX_DLL
42 # endif
43 #endif
44 #endif
```

I believe that redefining a macro without ‘undef’ is problematic, e.g., as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54943619/what-happens-if-i-redefine-a-macro-in-c-without-undef-directive) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976550/define-many-times-without-undef-is-it-legal).
Am I missing something here?
Thanks.

Comment: You'll generally get warnings when redefining macros. Do you?

Comment: The macros you show are defined only *once* because of the conditions.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude You man that sidx_dll_export in line 46 will always be defined?

Comment: Consider emailing the person who put their email at the top of the file? Does it build? Does it work? The various `if defined` around these might stop redefinitions. At a high level the `dllexport` is for functions  to be exported for use outside a dll/so which happens differently on *nix and Windows. How are you building it? For which platform?

Comment: If I paste this into MSVC, then `SIDX_DLL` is indeed defined twice, once as `__declspec(dllimport)` and once as `__declspec(dllexport)`. Yikes!

Comment: What's missing from this is what macros are defined in the project settings when building the source files that include the header files.

Comment: @doctorlove That is the problem, I mainly work with python and do not have to worry about macros. To speed up rtree query in python, I decided to wrap libspatialindex using ctypes. It has been only a week since I have started reading up on c++ syntax. I have not run this code and just wanted to understand its various parts.

Comment: Check it builds first. Then maybe try to write a dll/so yourself to understand some of it. Again at a high level some of these are for *nix and others for Windows

Comment: @doctorlove Well, I guess that is a good option that I have to take sooner or later.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How can I find out about the macros that are built during compilation and build?

Comment: Check makefiles and Visual Studio project files (whichever is relevant).

Comment: @Blaze I don't see how that can happen. Only one of those `#define` lines is executed, depending on `#ifdef DIX_DLL_EXPORT`.

Comment: @Barmar it happens if one of those `WIN` macros is defined, `__GNUC__` is not defined, `SIDX_DLL_EXPORT` is not defined and `SIDX_C_DLL` isn't defined either.

Comment: I see, it's getting defined in `Tools.h` and then getting redefined in `sidx_export.h`.

Comment: @Blaze you are not supposed to just paste it and hope it will work. You need a complete environment of a project with its settings and compilation flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No macro is illegally redefined here. Some may be defined more than once with identical definitions, which is OK. It's non-identical definitions that constitute a problem.

The DLL itself is always built with `SIDX_DLL_EXPORT` defined by the project settings. Code that uses the DLL is built without this macro being defined.

The second header is a part of the DLL. It is always compiled with `SIDX_DLL_EXPORT` being defined. Thus the macros defined by it, if any, are always identical to those defined in the first header. Such identical redefinition does not constitute a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you redefine it you need to redefine it using exactly the same list of preprocessing tokens.  This is true for function-macros and for object-macros.

From  [`6.10.3  Macroreplacement p2`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> An  identifier  currently  defined  as  an  object-like macro  **shall  not**  be  redefined  by  another #define preprocessing  directive  unless  the  second  definition  is  an  object-like macro definition  and  the  two replacement  lists  are  identical.
>
> Likewise,  an  identifier  currently defined   as   a   function-like macro   **shall   not**   be   redefined   by   another #define preprocessing  directive  unless  the  second  definition  is  a  function-like macro  definition that  has  the  same  number  and  spelling  of  parameters,  and  the  two replacement  lists  are identical.

So this definitions use `shall`.

Now, from `4.Conformance p2`:

> If a ‘‘shall’’or‘‘shall not’’requirement that appears outside of a constraint is violated, the behavior  is  undefined.

This is the official definition.  So, without dropping the macro symbol out from the environment of the preprocessor (using #undef) before you redefine it you get undefined behavior.

In case you find other situation in some implementations of C, this is not standardized.

Correctly it would be to insert different definitions in function of some condition that you set outside:

```
#if COND
#define M M1
#else
#define M M2
#endif
```

If you use some library that redefines it, for sure there are some macros that set the `COND` and make the things well defined.  You need to learn how to use the library.  Redefining it with different list of pp tokens is not valid.

Comment: The link given is to a draft of C99, which is obsolete.  The same provisions are also expressed by the two subsequent versions of the Standard, however.